# Attempting to concatenate dataframes, but get an AttributeError?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate two dataframes that look something like this:

Dataframe 1

```
            Beta   Diff
0   Week1    .5                 
1   Week2    .7     .2
2   Week3    .9     .2
```

Dataframe 2

```
            Beta   Diff
0   Week4    .11                 
1   Week5    .13     .2
2   Week6    .15     .2
```

However, when I try to run

```
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Does anyone know how I could go about fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? And can you give some concrete code that reproduces your example? Something similar does not fail for me with pandas 0.14.1

Comment: I'm using pandas ver 0.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a version problem. Updated to Pandas 0.13.1 and it works fine.

Comment: You should consider updating to the most recent version, which is  0.14.1